How to send video note
How to send video note in telegram bot via Python-telegram-bot
When sending a video in to bot, i receive a simple video that i send, instead of a video note.
async def send_video_note_to_user(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    video = update.message.video
    if video:
        fileid = video.file_id
        await update.message.reply_video_note(
            video_note = fileid
        )

I'm using update.message.reply_video_note to make a reply for video, coming to bot
It takes its File Id, than sends back, but as Video Note
That how it should work, i suppose, but instead of that, it replies me with a simple video, not video note.

The file_id that you pass to reply_video_note comes from a video. That's not supported by the bot api. You would need to pass the file id of a video note, or upload a new file.
